# How to simulate SHIFT+END key combination in Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I use keybd_event function to simulate SHIFT+END key combination but it doesn't work:

```
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT,0,0,0);
keybd_event(VK_END,0,0,0);
keybd_event(VK_END,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
```

The caret is move to the end of the line, but do not select the text(Highlight). Just like input a single END key.
Someone can help? Thanks very much~

---

I have solved this problem!
I used spy++ to find what happen when I use the keyboard to send the key Shift + End, and
I got these messages:

```
WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_SHIFT cRepeat:1 ScanCode:2A fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_END cRepeat:1 ScanCode:4F fExtended:1 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_END cRepeat:1 ScanCode:4F fExtended:1 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_SHIFT cRepeat:1 ScanCode:2A fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
```

and when I run the code above, I got these messages:

```
WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_SHIFT cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_SHIFT cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_END cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0 fExtended:1 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_END cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0 fExtended:1 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_SHIFT cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_SHIFT cRepeat:1 ScanCode:0 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
```

the window get a VK_SHIFT's WM_KEYUP message before a VK_END's WM_KEYDOWN message.
The different between the message is the value of "fExtended".
when I used the keyboard, the END key's fExtended value is 1, and when I run the code the value is 0.
So I try to set the fExtended value to 1, and I found the "dwFlags [in]" parameter of keybd_event function.
The key combination works when I run the code as follow:

```
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT,0x2A,0,0);
keybd_event(VK_END,0x4F,KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0,0);
keybd_event(VK_END,0x4F,KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT,0x2A,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UINT m_scanShift = MapVirtualKey(VK_SHIFT, 0);
UINT m_scanEnd   = MapVirtualKey(VK_END, 0);

keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, m_scanShift, 0, 0);
Sleep(10);
keybd_event(VK_END, m_scanEnd, 0, 0);
Sleep(10);
keybd_event(VK_END, m_scanEnd, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
Sleep(10);
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, m_scanShift, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer~But seems like it doesn't work, even if add the scan code and sleep time~I guess there maybe a Windows API to implement "select text" operation~

Answer (score 0):

Use both shift VK_LSHIFT and VK_RSHIFT down then VK_END and then both SHIFT UP
left and right at the same time will work for me